Using SSM to push terminal commands
I have an SSM environment in AWS, and I have client machines that are joining without any issues.  I am able to remote connect to the terminal and run commands, everything works up to this point.
Now I am trying to run terminal commands on the devices en masse. So I would like to, for example, run this:
echo 192.168.1.1 MyServer.domain.com >> /etc/hosts
apt install realmd
echo MyPassword | realm join -v --user=MyUsername domain.com
sudo reboot

So to package this script up in a tidy little unit of some kind that I can push out to devices as I require. But I can't seem to find any way that this can be done.

maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but SSM has a concept of "Documents" where you can store your scripts and supports a "Run Command" which can be used to run the document against your "fleet" of machines.
It even supports rate controls and more advanced feature.
Link for the documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/send-commands-multiple.html

It looks like Documents will accept powershell scripts only.

It supports shell scripts via the AWS-RunShellScript document.

Is there any info on how to use this?   I cant find any useful info, only that you end up with a JSON file, and no information on how or where to put the commands I need.

you can try this script :
#!/bin/bash

instances=(i-instance-1 i-instance-2)
for instance in "${instances[@]}"; do
    aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript"\
                         --targets "Key=instanceIds,Values=$instance"\
                         --parameters 'commands=["echo 192.168.1.1 MyServer.domain.com >> /etc/hosts","apt install realmd","echo MyPassword | realm join -v --user=MyUsername domain.com","reboot"]'
done


Not sure how or where to use this script.   So if I go to "Automation", and then "Create a Runbook".   Then I select "Run a Script", the scripting options are only Python and Powershell.  Not sure if either of these options will allow me to run the script you have suggested here?

You can run the shell script on any machine with aws CLI installed.

@Bisclavret Have you tried to run the script ?

Try the following:
aws ssm send-command \
--document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
--targets '[{"Key":"InstanceIds","Values":["instance-id"]}]' \
--parameters '{"commands":["#!/bin/bash","echo 192.168.1.1 MyServer.domain.com >> /etc/hosts","apt install realmd","echo MyPassword | realm join -v --user=MyUsername domain.com","sudo reboot"]}'

For your instances, use an array with your instance ids in it.
You would run this from your machine that has the aws cli on it and it would connect to all your remote instances.  Each line of your shell script would be a separate command in quotation marks.
Here is the reference I found on the AWS documentation for future reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html#walkthrough-cli-example-3
